# Is it possible to buil a UI application like WebOS on Android

Tags: android, user-interface, webos

The WebOS UI is really fantastic. And I doubt that if is possible to buil such an application on Android. For example, I want to manage the running applications in cards which is like the cards in WebOS and I can exit an application by just flipping the card away. That's cool but I don't know if it's possible to create such an application . If anyone have some ideas or sulutions,please give me a help . Thanks!

Comment: So design a launcher (home replacement app) that looks like the WebOS?? And have you done some coding of your own to get this started?

Comment: Yes.But I don't know how to get the running applications . Do you have some ideas ?

Comment: Some of the swiping functionality has been added in Android 4.1.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know much about webOS but its possible to build application like web-app using phonegap.
You can convert it into android app, i-phone app or black-berry app.
its really awesome.
visit this [link](http://phonegap.com/) to get more information.

Comment: thanks, but I am not going to build a web app. I want a normal app instead.

Comment: okies. i don't have much knowledge about it. so i am sorry. i can't help you.